# How to find out which guile module a binding is defined in?

Tags: scheme, lisp, guile

For example, which module should I use when I want to use the special form `define-values`?

Answer (score 2):

I usualy have local copy of [Guile Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.pdf) open somewhere and simply *Search* it.

According to manual `define-values` is part of an API, so you don't have to use any additional module.

Btw. All modules are described in chapter 7.

Comment: It turns out I was using a very old version, guile-1.8, which does not implement define-values.